# facebook registration plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbconnect

is there anyone can help me to put my personal privacy acceptation checkbox into facebook registration plugin form?

i can't find way to put acceptation checkbox and html tags inside fb form... how do you do for acceptations on your sites? :/

thanks

Comment: You want to put WHAT WHERE? can you show us some code of what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this documentation to insert the checkbox: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#custom_fields

Look at the "Custom Fields," there is an example of a checkbox being use.

Refer to this documentation to learn how to validate the checkbox and make sure it's checked:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/

Again, an example of a checkbox is used.

Comment: hi thanks, main problem now is that i can't insert custom html tags into fb form, for example i inserted privacy acceptation checkbox but i can't put a link to my site's privacy page :(